# Long-held HTTP request to PHP - active waiting consumes the CPU

Tags: php, jquery, asynchronous, comet

I have an jQuery code that send an long-held HTTP request (XHR), in respect to the Comet model.

That way one player signalizes that he's awaiting for his opponent to make an move. When the opponent performs the action (he wait from few seconds to about 2 minutes), the `pendingAction.txt` file is being created with the description of the opponent's move.

When server gets the XHR request from player, it starts the infinite loop, awaiting for the opponent's move:

```
while(1){
    if(file_exists("pendingAction.txt")){
        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
        $fileSize = filesize($fileName);
        if($fileSize){ //if file's not empty
            $commandsEncoded = fread($file, $fileSize);
            fclose($file);
            unlink($fileName);
            break;
        }
    }else{
        session_write_close(); //close the session prematurely to avoid sleep() and usleep() from locking other requests
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

I cannot extend the `sleep(...)` parameter too much, because it has an impact on the reaction time (player can notice the "lags").

But with such script, I really consume a lot of CPU (I have many active games on the server).

Is there a way to make it better? Maybe some **passive waiting** method instead of my active one?

I would like to **stick with the PHP/jQuery** and do not involve additional libraries or external scripts **if it's possible**.

Comment: You should just have the other user alert you when he's done with his actions (and pendingAction.txt is created).

Comment: @Shahar the other user note the server when he's done with his actions, but it cannot just simply notify another user as well (that would require one web browser to send something directly to another browser and I don't think it's possible with JavaScript/jQuery). That's why server gets the long-pull request from user in the first place (so he can respond when his opponent is done with his actions). But the active waiting of server for that is the problem here.

Comment: What you want seems to be WebSocket. I'm not going to explain how sockets and packets work, but in short they're what make MMORPG/other collaborative games possible, and WebSocket is especially designed to do so for web games. You can look into Mozilla's BrowserQuest as an example. However, if you don't want to deal with sockets/etc., look into pjax.

Comment: I am aware of WebSockets, but the server limitations forced me to work with something else. I know about the Comet model being one of solutions here, but I'm stuck with the active waiting of the server. Thank you for the pjax reference - I've never heard of it before (however, it looks like the jQuery/POST side solution which actually works for me, the server side waiting loop is a problem here).

Comment: What about polling. You send every say 5 seconds a request to the server, and the server returns either the description of the move or the information to keep on polling. This way you won't run in any timeouts or overuse the cpu

Comment: @MarioA yes, but will move (not solve) the problem of resources from server active waiting for file (CPU) to client active waiting for server (transfer).

Comment: @PolGraphic I dont't think that should be a problem. Poll requests are usually only some bytes, so no waste of ressources.